# Asp.net avoid reload entire page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a Master Page in a ASP.NET MVC 4 application. The master page has a menu with several items and each item is a link to a page.

The menu is a jQuery Accordion menu. When I select an item the entire page is reloaded and the accordion menu return to the original state.

To avoid this, I store the last menu opened and store it to an attribute of the header of the menu. On $(document).ready event I loop the headers and activate the menu but this makes an ugly effect to be seen.

How can I avoid reload of the entire page? I have to use the update panel in the MainContent of the ContentPlaceHolder of the Master Page? There is an example?

Comment: Master Pages and Content Placeholders are not part of the MVC framework. They are part of Asp.NET WebForms, a server side framework.  If you want to avoid postbacks, I would move to a SPA framework such as AngularJs.

Comment: Ok, Updatepanel are not applicable. MVC with ASPX engine (not Razor) support Master Page. There is no way to load the content page without refresh entire page?

Comment: Your solution for menu item is a harcoded and it is not recommanded. Lets say you want to add new item in future, are you going to update document.ready function every time? As Eric recommaned AngularJs is a good choice for single page application. Dont go for updatepanel it does have many side effect and also not applicable in MVC .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest an Ajax method.  You can find a tutorial here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/886473/Implementing-AJAX-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Since you're already using jQuery, another option would be to use $.get().  You can find a lot of tutorials related to that method, like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp).

Comment: I agree. Ajax is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After a lot of search and study of what I heard from you, I discovered a lot of framework as angularJs to build a Single Page Application. My need is to have a web application that has a list of items on the left and each of them retrieve a list of other items from server that have to be showed in the central panel of the page. I would like to avoid the reload of the entire page. So I bind a click event on each menu item and with te .load() method I retrieve the page to put in the selected element. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes you could use angular.  Jquery would work as well.  See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942105/jquery-get-request-on-http-url

Comment: I've implemented the ajax solution with .load method to redirect the page to an element of the main page. I noted that the _Layout main page is always created also if the content page is created as partial. Can I avoid it?

Comment: I think that question is beyond the scope of your original question.  I'd suggest asking a new question.  Including some sample code would help get is answered quickly!

Answer (score 1):

To make a difference when returning data between an 'normal' call to your action and one from an ajax-call use :

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) return PartialView("_Index", VM);
return View(VM);
```

The partial one will not include the lay-out. Otherwise you might get a funny looking page with the multiple top-bars.